# How to display a single record in database using Laravel and vue js?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

HI how can I display a single record on database using vue js ? I managed to display multiple but I cant display a single row. This is what i did .

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card-panel z-depth-5 grey lighten-2">
      <blockquote>
        <h3>
          <b>{{tutorial.attributes.title}}</b>
        </h3>
      </blockquote>
      <p class="flow-text">{{tutorial.attributes.content}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'tutorial',
  data: function() {
    return {
        tutorial = {
            id: '',
            content : null,
            title : '',
        },
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    const tutorial_id = this.id;
  },
  props: ['id'],
  methods: {
    get_tutorial: function() {
      //load the tutorials from the api
      axios
        .get('/api/view/' + tutorial_id )
        .then(response => {
          // asign it to data
          this.id = response.data.data.id;
          this.cpntent = response.data.data.content;

        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          // catch errors
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

this is my api route : (if i go to '/api/view/1') im successfully fetching the data i think my main mistake here is displaying it.

```
Route::get('/view/{id}','TutorialsController@view_tutorial');



 public function view_tutorial($id){ 
      return TutorialResource::collection(Post::all()->where('id',$id));
}
```

this is my blade :

```
@extends('layouts.main')
@section('styles')
<style>
.card-panel { 
  border-radius:5px;
}
</style>
@stop 
@section('content')

    <div class="app  ">
          <view-tutorial 
          :id="{{ $post->id }}" 
          >
          </view-tutorial>
    </div>

@endsection

@section('scripts')
<script>
<script src="{{mix('js/app.js')}}"></script>
</script>
@ensection
```

basically i have an href in my template  `:href="'/post/' + tutorial.id + '/' + tutorial.slug"` that when i click it redirects me to a page where i show the content of the post. this is my web route for that `Route::get('/post/{id}/{slug}', 'PostController@read_post');`
when i hit that it successfully redirect me to a view where in that view i will display data using vue js. In my template there is a props that will send the Id to the component and do some axios get request using that id so that i will get the specific record in my db. I can display  it with default blade syntax but for the sake of learning im trying it on vue js. Sorry for the noob question.

this is my errors : 
In my console : 
    SyntaxError: C:\projects\php\blogSite\resources\js\components\View_tutorial.vue: Unexpected token (19:17)

In my command prompt :

```
SyntaxError: C:\projects\php\blogSite\resources\js\components\View_tutorial.vue: Unexpected token (19:17)

  17 |   data: function() {
  18 |     return {
> 19 |         tutorial = {
     |                  ^
  20 |             id: '',
  21 |             content : null,
  22 |             title : '',
```

Thanks. I'll appreciate all the help.

Comment: Change `tutorial = { ...` to `tutorial: {...`

Comment: Besides from the answer(s), getting a single post like this `Post::all()->where('id',$id)` is not a good practice - you are fetching every post from the database and filtering on application level - let database to do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use route model binding. And get specific record from your database.

Read documents:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-model-binding